# Can I create .exe file from python project If I am working on mac?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I am working on Mac iOS, but I need to make my whole project as .exe file, not .dmg. It is meant to be running on Windows, I would like to use pyinstaller but I faced some problems, wondering if working on Mac has to be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyInstaller has can only target the OS it is running on: [Source](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#supporting-multiple-operating-systems). However, you could use a VM running Windows to build a Windows executable, or use something like wine (Example [here](https://github.com/paulfurley/python-windows-packager)) to package it without a VM.

Comment: You mean I cannot use Pyinstaller to create .exe file If my project is on Mac?

Comment: You can, you just need to either run a Virtual Machine (VM) with Windows on your Mac, or use something like Wine to run PyInstaller from. At no point do you need to use another computer. Some good, free VM software is [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), and wine can be downloaded [here](https://www.winehq.org/)